# Fix org-mode agenda highlighting

Tags: org-mode, font-lock, syntax-highlighting

I'm having an issue with highlighting in Org agenda:

[image]

Can't make the link and tags Gray when the item is marked as `Done`. I've tried to play with different properties of the font-lock definition, but nothing helped. Currently I'm using the foll

```
`(org-agenda-done      ((,class (:strike-through t :italic t :foreground ,comment))))
`(org-todo             ((,class (:foreground ,red))))
`(org-done             ((,class (:foreground ,green))))
`(org-link             ((,class (:underline t :foreground ,type))))
`(org-tag              ((,class (:foreground ,red))))
```

I'm not sure if it's the problem with my config or the way Org highlights these items?

Comment: You would have to modify the text properties dynamically when the state changes. My suggestion: live with it.  (Besides,  the links are still active no matter what the TODO state is, so why should they be grayed out?)